# How do I force neovim help file to be english, not chinese?

Tags: neovim

This is weird, but my helplang comes set as 'helplang=cn' but I don't have it on my .vimrc file.  Even if I add:
set helplang=us

at the very bottom of my .vimrc file, after I load vim, I get: helplang=cn

I am not sure where this is coming from... how can I figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... the .vimrc I copied was using vimcdoc.vim plugin, which forces it to chinese!